# should I expose derivable field in API?

Tags: javascript, api, schema, graphql, api-design

Suppose I have a field defined schemas - `id` and value looks like - `1234`. Now, in almost every situation clients would need to create a URL - for example `https://<server>/<path>/receipt/<id>`.

I'm in dilemma - should I expose URL field or should client create it at their end using id?

Answer (score 1):

I would say **yes** in this particular case, but it depends. Here are some things to consider:

Reasons to expose a computed field:

- Keeping the business logic hidden from the client. Often times we don't want to expose one or more of the fields used to determine the computed value, or don't want the client (or end user) to know which fields were used.
- Ensuring the client is agnostic to the business logic. If the business rules change, only the server code is impacted.
- Reducing code duplication. Code only has to be written once on the server, even if there are multiple applications that consume the API.

Reasons to not expose a computed field:

- The computed value concerns the client app's implementation details and not business rules. For example, it's probably not the server's place to return routes used inside a client app.
- How the value should be computed varies depending on some context, and it's not possible or practical to determine the context server-side. Exposing context-dependent fields inside of otherwise context-independent types can also cause headaches with regard to caching.